# How to make table for employee attendance system?

Tags: sql, database

I want to make data table for employee attendance management system, which may takes employee Id, employee Name, employee Entry, employee break in, employee break out, employee exit. you may suggest me some more fields if you like to suggest.

I have made three tables :   1. Employee: ( employeeId, employeeName)   2. Attendance: ( Id, employeeName, action, actionTime)   3. Action: ( Id, actionName). What I am doing wrong and what should I do for Improvements. Thanks in Advance for help.

There is picture of my home page that I am making an app in Django

[image: Home page]

Comment: Show us your current table definitions. Describe what's wrong, and what you want instead.

Comment: What makes you believe that you are "doing something wrong"?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to save records of employee in a fashion/ way so that I may store proper records of employee like : employee Name, entry time, break In time, break out time, Exit. total hours spent

Comment: I think there is something wrong in Table 1 and Table 2. please suggest me for any changes I may change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given information,you can normalize your tables like below.

```
 Employee: ( EmployeeId (PK), EmployeeName)
 Action: ( ActionId (PK), ActionName)
 Attendance: ( AttendanceId (PK), EmployeeId (FK), ActionID(FK), ActionTime)
```

Comment: I think ActionId is unnecessary. isn't it ?

Comment: With out ActionId how will you identify a particular Action in the attendance table?

Comment: what would be the foreign keys..of what table

Comment: ActionId is foreign key for Attendance table and EmployeeId is foreign key for Action table.